# How to find a video element within an owl-carousel slide and then set owl-carousel control's css only for that specific slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote this to find a video element within an owl-carousel slide and then set owl-carousel control's CSS only (this control appears on runtime of webpage) for that specific slide.

The code is not working at all, I'm new to use js.

```
$(".item").children().find("video").each(function(){
    var d = document.getElementByClass('owl-controls');
    d.style.bottom = y_pos+'10px';
});
```

For the HTML

```
<div id="post-media" class="owl-carousel item-2">
    <div class="item"><img src="images/fullimage1.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
    <div class="item">
        <video controls="" class="embed-responsive-item" style="width:100%; height:100%">
            <source src="video/clip1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-controls clickable">
        <div class="owl-pagination">
            <div class="owl-page active">
                <span class=""></span>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-page">
                <span class=""></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only desire shifting the position of `owl-controls` no need for jquery. You can use CSS only:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-controls
{
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know css3, you can use same queries with jQuery

```
$(".item video").each(function(){
    var d = document.getElementByClass('owl-controls');
    d.style.bottom = y_pos+'10px';
});
```